# Saving a buffered image with lose less compression

Tags: java

I have a java program which capture screen shots at a regular interval using java Robot class.But since it takes screen shots very often(~5 sec) it could fill my hard disk very soon.
Is there any way through which i could decrease the size of image before saving, but could regenerate the original image without losing the quality.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException;
import java.sql.*;  
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
class wtd
{
public static BufferedImage getImage()throws Exception
       {
            Dimension screenDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
              Robot robot = new Robot();


               BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) screenDim.getWidth(),(int) screenDim.getHeight()));
               return image;



    }
      public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    { 
                 long id=0;
                       try{
                           while(true)
                           {
                       BufferedImage originalImage=getImage();

                          ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", new File("D:/"+id+".jpg"));
                                         id++;


                                 }
                   }

               catch(Exception e){}

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: yes please wait for a minute.

Comment: "...decrease the size of image before saving, but could regenerate the original image without losing the quality"  If you manage this (apart from saving as a png or something) I think the world would want to know about it!

Comment: @SteveSmith   i think it is possible, i have heard about the term lossless compression

Comment: Perhaps you could save the pictures after the first one as the difference between the two pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are already compressed, using another compression processing will not be very helpful : you will spare space but not necessarily a lot of.

If your images are not or few compressed, you could use classic compression tools as zip that allows lossless data compression. 
You have multiple level of compression but more the level of compression is high, more the processing time is long.
So according to the cpu power, the available cpu thread number and the size of your images, you should use a level more or less important of compression.

For example the [java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) class allows to create a zip with a specific level of compression by invoking the `setLevel(int level)` method.
Then you could use the `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` class to extract the archive.

---

Edit for a code example :

Here is a not tested example by using the `javax.imageio.ImageIO.write()` JDK 8 specific method that allows to write a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` into an `java.io.OutputStream` object:

```
  // Here is the capture bufferedImage from your application
  BufferedImage screenShot = ...;

  // You create the zip file and you add entry that will store the image
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("yourZipFile.zip");
  ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fileOut);
  zipOut.setLevel(9); // 9 is the max level      
  ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("screenshot-2017-03-24_12-03-30.jpg");
  zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

  // you get the bytes from the image 
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(screenShot, "jpg", out);
  byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

  // you write the bytes in the zipOutputStream
  zipOut.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  zipOut.close();
```

Comment: could  java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream  can compress a BufferedImage or first i have to save it and then compress the saved file and resave the compressed file.

Comment: You don't need to save the image in a file. I will edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lossless compression you can give a try to [Lepton](https://github.com/dropbox/lepton) which [achieves](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2016/07/lepton-image-compression-saving-22-losslessly-from-images-at-15mbs/):

> a 22% savings reduction for existing JPEG images, by predicting coefficients in JPEG blocks and feeding those predictions as context into an arithmetic coder. Lepton preserves the original file bit-for-bit perfectly. It compresses JPEG files at a rate of 5 megabytes per second and decodes them back to the original bits at 15 megabytes per second, securely, deterministically, and in under 24 megabytes of memory.

Comment: I want to know that is it could directly compress the buffered image or i have to first save it as jpeg file and then i have to compress and resave it.